# Mutation.types.yaml access to specific types of users

Tags: graphql, attributes, roles

I have a Symfony project. I use graphQl bundle and PHP annotations. I try to give access to different roles on specific mutations, but I can not find the solution. Also, the users that do not have access should not even see the mutations.

I tried to modify the Mutation.types.yaml, this is the last configuration try, but I had tried others :

```
`      somethingCreate:
        type: 'SomethingSettings'
        args:
          fields:
            type: 'CreateSomethingSettingsTypeInput'
        security: 'is_granted("ROLE_ADMIN" || Role("ROLE_DEV")'
        resolve: '@=mutation("App\\Mutation\\SomethingSettingsMutation::createSomethingSettings", args["fields"])'`
```

I also tryed to modify the Mutations resolver, added annotations :

```
`   #[GQL\Mutation(type: 'SomethingSettings')]
    #[GQL\IsPublic("hasAnyRole(['ROLE_DEV', 'ROLE_ADMIN'])")]
    #[GQL\Arg('fields', type: 'CreateSomethingSettingsTypeInput')]
    public function createSomethingSettings($fields)
    {  logic to create something 
}
```

`

I tried to use the authorization checker but that does not work also. Any advice would be very much appreciated :)